# Синзронизация локальной дирректории с удалённой для приложения на електрон

Tags: javascript, node.js

Хочу написать приложение на electron.js по типу Лаунчера для игры, но для этого мне нужна синхронизация удалённых файлов с CDN и локальными файлами, такую програму пользователь сможет скачать себе на компьютер, по этому использовать SFTP не вариант, хотелось бы именно через CDN. Кто знает как это можно такое реализовать, и чтобы менее ресурсозатратно было.

То есть, к примеру, файл text.txt лежит у меня на компьютере, пользователь запускает програму и та проверят, не обновлён ли файл на CDN, если файл обновился, значит обновляет его на компьютере, если файла на компьютере вообще нет, то загружает его (суть в синхронизации).

Возможно существует какой-то node.js модуль для этого, но вот уже четвёртый день ничего не могу найти...

Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Ну проверяют чек сумму файла с тем что скачано и с тем что на сервере и докачивают если таковы различия найдены. Ну а для скачивания используют какой-нибудь загрузчик с сохранением данных под электрон, чтобы можно было отложить скачивание в случае чего.

Comment: А чек сумма файла это что такое? Есть какое-то полное название?

Comment: "CDN" ваш или чужой?

Comment: Свой конечно, но никаких подключений нельзя создавать с помощью пароля, потому что этот код будет открытым. Меня заинтересовал вариант про checksum, кто нибудь знает как реализовать это для удалённого и локального файла?

Comment: тогда вы можете присылать JSON а не как в примере из предыдущего вопроса

Comment: Можно более подробнее? Какой именно JSON?

Comment: с информацией - необходимой для "синхранизации" - [ имя файла, дата создания, ..., ссылка на скачивание, хэш, ... , ] чтобы не было необходимости парсить HTML страницу

Comment: Такой JSON файл нужно будет постоянно вручную писать, или есть модуль какой-то для этого? Вручную это не вариант.

Comment: а парсить HTML - вариант ???? как файлы будут попадать на "сервер", чем планируется отдавать информацию о файлах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему тем, что написал сервер на node.js, который сверяет последние даты обновлений двух файлов, и если файл, что лежит на сервере обновился, то и обновлять локальный.

Answer (score 0):

---

### синхронизация, разбор понятия

- получение информации о файлах с сервера
- сверка
- скачивание файлов

---

### получение информации о файлах с сервера

#### автор вопроса

в [предыдущем посте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1088403/232932), привел вот такой пример:
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.5.0/

```
Index of /download/release/v13.5.0/
../
docs/                                              18-Dec-2019 17:34                   -
win-x64/                                           18-Dec-2019 17:24                   -
win-x86/                                           18-Dec-2019 17:36                   -
SHASUMS256.txt                                     18-Dec-2019 18:51                3121
SHASUMS256.txt.asc                                 18-Dec-2019 18:51                3658

... и т.д. и .т.п
```

#### я же предлагаю

использовать JSON для передачи данных

---

### сверка

сверка локальных файлов с полученными данными - определение что необходимо скачать

тут необходимо определить критерии для обновления

---

### скачивание файлов nodejs

#### без библиотек

поискать на stackoverflow.com

- [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[nodejs] как скачать файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[nodejs]%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[nodejs] How to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[nodejs]%20How%20to%20download%20a%20file)

> [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11944932/4794368)

или написать самому (доки nodejs)

- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/
- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/http.html
- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/fs.html

#### поискать NPM пакет

с именем схожи на консольные утилиты линукс

- wget - https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=wget
- curl - https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=curl

по ключевым словам

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:curl,wget,http,fetch,get,download

по ключевым словам в консоли

```
npm find "download" "download manager"
```

#### поискать на github

- https://github.com/search?q=nodejs+download+manager